# How to fix displaying nickname from GitHub in bitbucket?

Tags: git

When I push something to Bitbucket in column Author displaying my nickname from GitHub. How to fix it?

Comment: You can look the .git/config. For more ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191918/change-github-account-username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look first in `.git/config` if you haven't forgotten some credentials that are supposed to apply to your previous project and/or hosting platform.

If not, Bitbucket might rely on the e-mail address of either the author or committer. In this case, this should be configured directly from Bitbucket's user interface.